# Trouble with menus in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu

I'm struggling to finish my first Word Press Theme and I've stumbled upon baffling problem: one of my menus - in this case a footer menu -  is not visible.
This the actual code I have:

```
</div><!--#main-->
    <footer>
        <div class="bottom">
            <nav><?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container_class' => 'footer-menu', 'theme_location' => 'footer-menu', 'menu' => 'Footer Menu' ) ); ?>
            </nav><!--.bottom nav-->
            <div class="info">whatever &copy;2015</div>
        </div><!--.bottom-->
        <?php wp_footer(); ?>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what Chrome's `view-source` is showing in appropriate place:

```
<div class="bottom">
    <nav>           </nav><!--.bottom nav-->
    <div class="info">EEAC &copy;2015</div>
</div><!--.bottom-->
```

Meanwhile, I am 100% positive I got right names in the Dashboard. 
Other menus I've got are working. There are 3 more of them, all made using very similliar code. No problem there. Just this one.
CSS is also very similliar, no ground breaking changes, so that's not the problem I think.
Have You got any idea what might be causing the problem here?

EDIT: It does however show up on the single.php and page.php. Only place it's not included is main page so far.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing:

```
'sort_column' => 'menu_order'
```

Comment: Downvoted for pointing out non-existent parameter . . . ok https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/